# Save user's ID in database with Symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

still getting to grips with Symfony so please excuse me if this is already asked. I don't quite understand how to send data to forms to be processed properly so am need of a bit of guidance.

My issue is i wish to save my logged in user's ID into the database when they are creating a new gecko (so that this gecko's profile shows for only this user logged in). I am using FOSUserBundle by the way.

I know i can get the current user's id by using something like `$user = $this->getUser()->getId();` However, i would like to save this into the database.

createAction:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Gecko();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gecko_show', array('name' => $entity->getName())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

GeckoType:

```
<?php

namespace Breedr\GeckoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class GeckoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('aquisitionDate')
            ->add('morph')
            ->add('sex', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Male' => 'Male',
                    'Female' => 'Female'
                )
            ))
            ->add('genetics')
            ->add('bio')
            ->add('bred', 'checkbox', array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('hatchling', 'checkbox', array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('clutch', 'text', array(
                'data' => 0,
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('imageFile', 'file', array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('user_id', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => $user,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Breedr\GeckoBundle\Entity\Gecko'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'breedr_geckobundle_gecko';
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help with this. I just can't understand how the data is used/sent. Thanks in advance :)

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly sorry if you know this, but you'll need correct relationships set up between your Gecko and User entities.

Note your @ORM annotation may be different from mine (or you could be using YAML or whatever). My use is:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

This should be in your Gecko entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Your\NameSpace\Entity\User", inversedBy="geckos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

This should be in your User entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Your\NameSpace\Entity\Gecko",mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $geckos;
```

Note you'll need to [generate getters & setters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html) etc.

To save your new Gecko:

```
$gecko = new Gecko();
$gecko->setUser($this->getUser());

$form = $this->createForm(new GeckoType(), $gecko);

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $form->submit($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $entityManager->persist($gecko);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // do something with success

    } else {

        // show errors by flash message or whatever
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you read up on the symfony [forms documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) & the  [databases & doctrine documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) as that has most of the information you need for getting started.

Comment: The outer `if` is unnecessary. A `$form->handleRequest($request);` followed by `if ($form->isValid()) {` is sufficient.

Comment: I'm going to try this right now and see if it works. I knew about relationships but i wasn't sure if i needed it for doing this. Thank you for this, will report back soon with any issues :)

Comment: @keyboardSmasher i dropped the outer if and it does indeed work fine :)